# How can I consistently tell OpenSUSE to refresh the clock / current time?

Tags: virtualbox, opensuse, ntp, clock

I use OpenSUSE in a VM and sometimes want to save the machine and get back to work later. I haven't had much success with hibernate or suspend, so I simply save the state of the machine and resume later.

Most of the time the clock is wrong and shows the time from when I saved it, which is somewhat expected. Eventually it will re-sync and work on it's own, but sometimes that takes an hour.

The strange part is also if I try to go and manually set the time of the click it will complain about the NTP dbus service not working, so I can't even fix the clock manually :(

The reason I care about this is because TLS negotiation (for SSL/HTTPS) usually fails if the clock is off by a few hours.

- Should I set the date from the command line ?
- Can I restart the time service somehow?
- Is there a better way to save the machine? I would use suspend/resume but it doesn't do anything when I try.

Comment: What VM technology are you using? There may be a way to trigger a clock update when the machine state is restored.

Comment: VirtualBox, not sure how CMOS timer style stuff is emulated

Comment: @Gilles Stop removing the OpenSUSE tag please this question is related to OpenSUSE.

Comment: Also stop removing the ntpd tag because it's the daemon used to control this in OpenSUSE.

Comment: No, this question should not have the [tag:opensuse] tag. A distribution tag means “this question is specific to this distribution”, not “I am running this distribution”. Answers to your question do not depend on the distribution, or only in minor aspects, so this question should not have a tag that means “doesn't apply to other distributions”.

Comment: This question is specific to OpenSUSE. Stop removing the tag.

Comment: How is syncing the time distro-specific? It has nothing to do with your distro

Comment: The distro-specific tags are only for the very few cases where the question is specific to a distribution. The fact that you're using distributionX is not a reason to tag as such. What you describe here is generic and about virtualbox. You just happened to have come upon it while using openSuSe. [The same goes](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/109/22222) for the Linux tag.

Comment: You've now had various community members, including two mods, explain to you why you were tagging incorrectly and yet you still insist on using the wrong tags. Stop it!

Answer (score 0):

Put `ntpd -qg` in `/root/.profile` and run it by invoking a login shell via `su -` first thing you log in.